# facing Errors while installing Composer in xampp server

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am facing some errors while installing composer in xampp server.
it will showing the below msg
[image]

This is my php.ini file image
[image]

after installing the the dll file it will showing some error like below
[image]

Can any one suggest some solution.to how to solve this.

Comment: do the `C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mcrypt.dll` file exists?

Comment: That file is not exist in given folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the comments:

Your PHP install is missing files that are referenced in php.ini.

I suggest that you reinstall your XAMPP. (recommended option)

Or

Try to find all modules referenced in php.ini that are missing and manually download then and put in `C:\xampp\php\ext\` folder.

Comment: i have installed all the dll file that recomended

Comment: still i am facing another issue

Comment: another issue? please, open a new question. Did my answer helped you to solve the problem related with this specific question (the missing php_mcrypt.dll file)?

Comment: i have included that all the .dll file that are required.

Comment: still, i am not able to install composer